# Comparing 2 arrays with 200,000+ values each

Tags: ruby, xml, performance, algorithm

I have a stack of data in 200,000+ XML files, which are updated/created every week. So, each week, I have to parse each XML file, check whether there are new XML files being created, then update my database with all updated data. In between, if there is new XML file, then my database will not have that record, so I have to create a new row.

Here's my workflow plan:

1. Put all table X row ID into array A. Let's say 200,000 numerical values.
2. Parse each XML files and gather each XML's ID (ID will be the same as my table X ID), and store in array B. Let's say now I have 200,010 numerical values, with 10 new records compared to my current table X.
3. Compare array A and array B to see which values do not exist.
4. Put the 10 new values into array C.
5. Create new record in table X with that 10 new IDs from array C.
6. Parse each XML file again, and store the desired values to my table X row-column.
7. So now my table X will have 200,010 records, and each are updated, and the new 10 records will also now in the table X.

The problem I have to do this is because I can't get any information of any new XML file created by the vendor. They just give me a stack of files.

Any better way to do it? I'm worried that my system will crash when they compare two arrays with 200,000+ values. Thanks.

Comment: What language? How do you get the XML files? There are many ways. Tried something like MD5 to check the files? Remember what filenames exists? Lookt at the change date?

Comment: Ruby. XML files are all stored in a zipped format, have to unzip and store in a temp directory. The ID is also the filename, maybe I can do this for step 2. No change date. Just raw XML data.

Comment: Why do you need to parse the XML files a second time (step 6)? Isn't it enough to parse each XML file ones and **insert** the xml-content to your table if ID is unknown or **update** the xml-content if the ID is already known?

Comment: Take advantage of the database's ability to quickly locate matches. That is what it is made for. As others have mentioned, create an indexed field for the md5 value. Generate the md5 for a file and see if you have it in the table. If you want to be really thorough/paranoid, also create a field for the length of the XML and compare that too, or just normalize the XML before generating the md5. But let the database compare the values. No need to create huge arrays in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar. In the end I did it like this:

1. Baseline the whole setup by iterating over each record in all XML files, normalizing the item (removing newlines, cleaning up whitespace, substituting certain characters) and then doing a per record MD5 sum. Also import the record.
2. When I get new data, I iterate through the records (SAX would be a good idea), if the record is not yet in the DB (based on UID) or has changed (based on MD5 sum) it gets imported.

This works pretty well for what we usually need it for (around 350k records spread through around 100 files), but also worked ok-ish with (much) more data. It's a wild mix of several tools, including Bash, AWK, sed, grep, the wonderful [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and Ruby, and would be in dire need of a proper rewrite.

Comment: So use checksums and use the database do the heavy lifting instead of using arrays.

Comment: @mu Yes, basically. Also there's a proliferation of tools because some or faster than other for certain tasks, but of course it could all be done from within Ruby (speed tests weren't exactly encouraging though).

Comment: If one were daring one could build PL/Ruby for PostgreSQL and do it both in Ruby and in the database at the same time.

Comment: Looks like there's a lot to do! Thanks!

Comment: Doing 200k queries for values is going to  be slower than retrieving the list and checking it in memory. And the hash serves no purpose since the OP seems to only need to distinguish based on the included ID.

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare the files in your ruby script. Use MD5 Sums. That should work unless the content of the XML is changed. And then it is not the same XML at all.

Comment: Even if each week the vendor will re-export the data to XML files. So I should use the old files' MD5 to compare with new files' MD5? I still need to put them in array right? As in, I need to write the script in Ruby still.

Comment: Yes MD5 is good thing! Also I wold recommend to put it all in hash table in Ruby to check what new things have appeared very quickly.

Comment: Oh, can you ensure that data from previous export will be exported to the same file? If not then MD5 or other such thing may be __only__ way to identify "data", other than compare it all.

Comment: The previous export file names will be the same with the new export file names. I think you guys have just given headstarts to me! Now, if new file `011.xml` cannot find any existing old file `011.xml` to compare MD5, that means I have to create new record based on this file. Right?

Comment: "I still need to put them in array right? As in, I need to write the script in Ruby still.", no you don't have to write all of it in Ruby. Look at the `md5` command for your OS if you're on Mac OS or Linux. If you are on Windows you can probably find one easy enough. Let that utility create the checksums and append the resulting hashes to a text file, and read that. The command-line md5 should be a lot faster. For example, I just generated hashes for 24K+ files in just under 1.5 minutes using `/sbin/md5` on a Mac Pro.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. If the XML files are big, use a SAX Parser for parsing (you don't need to keep the whole file in memory).
2. Sort the array A, so you can use a binary search.
3. Iteratively read each XML-file, if the ID from the file is not within your array A, store it in your table X (no need to keep a second array B).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pretty good solution. A little change will make it faster.

In step 3 you "Compare array A and array B to see which values do not exist."
I assume you are iterating through array B (xml), and looking values in array A (database).

When you find a value in array A, be sure to remove it from array A (database), making array A smaller and smaller as you go through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you ignore XML files with existing IDs, rather than importing any changes in them (your question implies that existing files don't change, or that you don't care about changes), a slight modification of your procedure will be optimal:

1. Load all the existing IDs from your database into a [set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html), rather than an array.
2. Parse each XML file, extracting its ID, and check if it's in the set.
3. If the file is not in the set, process it and add it to the database.

There's no need to do two passes over your data, because you can check if the file has already been processed, then immediately process it if it hasn't.